# DataTable Intersection Operation

Tags: datatable

I have two datatables defined like this;

Dim db1, db2 As New DataTable

db1 and db2 hold results from different queries but the columns in both are exactly the same. I would like to create another datatable which consists of records that are in both db1 and db2. i.e I want the intersection of the two datatables. Is there an easy way to do this?

(The resultant datatable will be used to populate a gridview.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try in this way.

```
        // Declare Data Table and Data View
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
        DataView dv = new DataView();

        dt1.Columns.Add("Col1");
        dt1.Columns.Add("Col2");
        dt1.Columns.Add("Col3");

        dt2.Columns.Add("Col1");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Col2");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Col3");

        // Initialize Data Table and Data View

        dt1.Rows.Add("A", "B", "C"); // Testing data for data table 1; actual data will come from your query
        dt1.Rows.Add("E", "F", "G"); //                                 ==

        dt2.Rows.Add("A", "B", "C");
        dt2.Rows.Add("U", "V", "W");// Testing data for data table 2; actual data will come from your query
        dt2.Rows.Add("X", "Y", "Z");//                                  ==


        // Merge Data Table into temporary Data Table
        dtTemp = dt1;  //Initialize dt1 value in to dtTemp
        dtTemp.Merge(dt2);// Merge it with dt2 you will get the 

        // Use Data View to get disticnt values
        dv = new DataView(dtTemp);
        dt3 = dv.ToTable(true, "Col1", "Col2", "Col3");// Remember, it is for intersection not for union
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [VB.NET with LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/aa904594.aspx) you could do it like this:

```
Dim db3 = db1.Intersect(db2)
```

From there just use db3 to populate your GridView.